# Последний блок строки Bootstrap переходит на новую строку

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подключил только сетку Bootstrap, сайт чистый, никаких стилей нет пока что.
Такая проблема, создаю три блока:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

При этом последний из этих блоков переходит на новую строку, хотя должны все три блока быть на одном уровне.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: Дык все так же само делаю :(

Comment: Добро пожаловать в Бутстрап. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в вашу разметку вот такие классы:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо. Я просто удалил из стилей Бутстрапа стили для * :) Вернул и все заработало